# Calculate mirror angle

Tags: trigonometry

Hi I'm working on a project where I need to calculate what angle a mirror needs to be at in order to reflect a source of light onto a particular location on a surface. A lot like this: [Help finding solution for trigonometric equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34193/help-finding-solution-for-trigonometric-equation)

Only without the stuff about cylinders.

[image]

Judging by this diagram how can I solve for $C$? Ivella states that $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$ but I don't see how? Should it be $c= \frac{b-a}{2}$ ?

That seems more likely, though I'm not sure about that either.

Comment: Probably a slip. You want to solve $a+c=b-c$, which leads to $c=\dfrac{b-a}{2}$

Comment: ah yes of course I see that now, as I had suspected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since angle of incident$=$ angle of reflection
We get
$ a+c=b-c$ ..............$ 1$

Also from figure we get 
$\frac{\pi}{2}-(b-c)-c=\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$
 Gives $\frac{\pi}{2}-b= \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$
This gives $b$ and we know $a$ as it is our incident ray angle,so from $1$ we get $ c$